# Find all solutions to complex sum for certain point in complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

I am currently learning about complex equations. I am now familiar with equations like $2z^2+(4+i)z+(1-2i)=0$. So I tried finding the solutions to more difficult(?) equations like: $$\sum_{j=1}^ke^{\varphi_j i}=a+bi$$
So what I want to do, is to find all of the $k$ complex numbers with an absolute value of $1$ which when all added together result in the same point $a+bi$.

When $k=1$ or $k=2$ the solution is fairly easy: when $k=1$, then there is at most one solution and when $k=2$ there can only be zero or two solutions (I think), because if you can find one solution you can mirror this solution on the real axis and obtain a second one. But for $k>2$ it does not seem as simple to me.

Comment: For intuitive insight, that may come to nothing, consider the problem geometrically.  Further, assume that $k=3$.  Then you want to form a quadrilateral with one point at $P_1 = (0 + i[0])$, one point at $P_4 = (a + bi)$, and the other two points, $P_2, P_3$ unspecified.  The only other constraint is that 3 of the sides (excluding the side going from $P_1$ to $P_4$) must each have length $(1)$.  It is clear that this geometric constraint will generalize to a polygon with $n$ sides, where $P_n = (a + bi)$, and where all sides (excluding the $P_1$ to $P_n$ side) must each have length $(1)$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
Thanks for your tip. I just don't understand why $P_1=(0+i[0])$? I am also unsure what $i[0]$ means, I have never seen that way of writing a complex number before. (I am referring to the squared brackets).

Comment: I used the somewhat artificial notation of $(0) = (0 + i[0])$ simply to emphasize that the real component of $(0)$ and the imaginary component of $(0)$ are both equal to $(0)$.  It has no significance, other than that.  I used the syntax of $(0 + i[0])$ only because I was using `(` and `)` as *outer dividers*, so for contrast, I used `[` and `]` as  *inner dividers*.